# Programmatically inserting a blockquote followed by a new line in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have successfully created a plugin for ckeditor 5 which allows users to select one or more previous posts from a page and upon clicking an "apply quotes" button, it inserts the selected posts in to the editor view one after the other as blockquotes.

This works fine, however, I would like to have the cursor be on a new line after the last blockquote so the user can add their own comments.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried appending a paragraph tag tot he list of quotes, but this appears as a new paragraph WITHIN the last quote, not after it.

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: I completely modified my previous response because I didn't understand what do you wanted to achieve. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a simple function that adds to the editor quoted text and a paragraph for the user reply.

```
/**
 * @param {String} author An author of the message.
 * @param {String} message A message that will be quoted.
 */
function replyTo( author, message ) {
    // window.editor must be an instance of the editor.
    editor.model.change( writer => {
        const root = editor.model.document.getRoot();
        const blockQuote = writer.createElement( 'blockQuote' );
        const authorParagraph = writer.createElement( 'paragraph' );
        const messageParagraph = writer.createElement( 'paragraph' );

        // Inserts: "Author wrote:" as bold and italic text.
        writer.insertText( `${ author } wrote:`, { bold: true, italic: true }, authorParagraph );

        // Inserts the message.
        writer.insertText( message, messageParagraph );

        // Appends "Author wrote" and the message to block quote.
        writer.append( authorParagraph, blockQuote );
        writer.append( messageParagraph, blockQuote );

        // A paragraph that allows typing below the block quote.
        const replyParagraph = writer.createElement( 'paragraph' );

        // Appends the block quote to editor.
        writer.append( blockQuote, root );

        // Appends the reply paragraph below the block quote.
        writer.append( replyParagraph, root );

        // Removes the initial paragraph from the editor.
        writer.remove( root.getChild( 0 ) );

        // And place selection inside the paragraph.
        writer.setSelection( replyParagraph, 'in' );
    } );

    editor.editing.view.focus();
}
```

If you will have some questions about how to adjust it to your code, I would like to see code that you wrote. It will allow understanding what you did.

Of course, you can see the proposed code as an online demo – https://jsfiddle.net/pomek/s2yjug64/

Comment: The question was about setting the selection **after** the block quote. Your answer shows how to set it inside the block quote.